# Clean tag shows in iTunes app but not in Music app - iPhone 6, iOS8

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, music.app, id3-tag

**Edit:** I do in fact see a [E] tag for explicit songs downloaded from iTunes, but as the title states, I want to see a [C] tag for clean songs downloaded from iTunes.

---

I have edited some song meta data using mp3tag to make the [Clean] tag show up in iTunes. This worked perfectly, but after syncing the songs to my iPhone, the tag does not show up in the Music app.

I figured it was an issue with how I added the tag, but then today I downloaded one of the free songs of the week, which displays a [C] in the iTunes app on my phone. I downloaded it and went to it in the Music app, but it does **not** show the [C] tag in any playlist, in the song tab, or in the Artist tab (navigating to the song on that tab). It also does **not** show a [C] or [Clean] on the Now Playing screen.

How do I get the tag to show up in the Music app? Or does the Music app simply not show the [Clean] tags (and only shows the [Explicit] tags)?

Comment: I would imagine that the [Clean] tag isn't showing up simply because the [E] tag makes it redundant. If a song isn't explicit, it follows that it must be clean. It's probably kept in the iTunes app for legal reasons so users with restrictions (such as children) can download a clean version of a known explicit song.

Answer (score 1):

Going along with Stuart H's comment, I believe the music app for iOS only looks for explicit tags on a song because they can be used for setting restrictions on the device, clean tags are unnecessary because the songs are considered to be clean unless an explicit tag is found. So having a tag for every song would be pretty useless and clutter up the UI.